# Can Passwall be used to enter an area protected by Forbiddance?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

Let's say the BBEG has their Tower of Doom protected by a *[Forbiddance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forbiddance)* spell and rather than kick down the front door, the party wants to sneak in all ninja-like. To do this, they want to use a spell to get inside quietly.

The relevant wording in the *Forbiddance* spell description says:

> You create a ward against *magical travel*...For the duration, creatures
>   can't teleport into the area or use portals...to enter the area.

I'm assuming *[Dimension Door](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door)* wouldn't work as the description starts off with

> You teleport yourself...

But, what about *[Passwall](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/passwall)*?

> A passage appears at a point of your choice that you can see on a...surface within range...

Does the *magical travel* wording of the *Forbiddance* spell prevent *Passwall* from working, or **can *Passwall* be used to enter an area protected by *Forbiddance*?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes*

The description of *Forbiddance* makes it quite clear that it only prevents travel *via* magic, such as teleportation or planar travel. *Passwall* does not transport anything, it changes the structure of a wall to allow passage through it (note that its school is *Transmutation*, implying it changes structures, unlike most travelling spells which tend to be in the *Conjuration* school), and nothing in the description of *Forbiddance* suggests that magic cannot affect structures in its area of effect.

*: Well, technically no. *Passwall*, as explained above, does not transport or enter anything. But creatures can pass through an opening created by *Passwall*, which is what I assume you meant.

Comment: *That's exactly what I meant, and I've adjusted my question to reflect that.